# Wanting to Run some init code in AngularJS with ui-router before menu displays

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm wanting to run some initialization code before my actual menu shows.  That is, in my real app, I have an http resource I want to load that will effect what choices are shown in the menu choice list.  More specifically, I want to put up a "waiting" message when my program first runs until the http resource completely loads.  I've been experiminent with resolves but that seems to only help me after the menu has loaded.

I'm hoping not to have to use the bootstrap pattern since I want to do this in multiple places in my app, not just the first time it runs.  I'm also not a big fan of the bootstrap pattern. It seems a little contrived to me.

I'm trying to do this with a very simple example first I have loaded here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eehhA1CR2sEMQZrQBo3E?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('svccApp', [
    'ui.router'
]);


app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',

    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$q,$timeout) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                template: '<p>HOME HERE</p>',
                controller: 'HomeController as vm'
            }).
            state('about', {
                url: '/about',
                template:   '<p>about here title: {{vm.title}}</p>',  //'index4template.html',
                controller: 'AboutController as vm',

                resolve: {
                    title: function(){
                        return 'from title function';
                    }
                }
            });
    }]);


var injectParamsAbout = ['title'];
var AboutController = function (title) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = title;
};
AboutController.$inject = injectParamsAbout;
angular.module('svccApp').controller('AboutController', AboutController);

var injectParamsHome = [];
var HomeController = function () {
};
HomeController.$inject = injectParamsHome;
angular.module('svccApp').controller('HomeController', HomeController);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using parent and child *(not sure if this is not your not-liked bootstrap pattern)*. I created/updated [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wd1mSbsnI6Wi0Cd4d4ZK?p=preview)

```
// this is loaded immediately
// and that means, that user will see ...loading... ASAP
.state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    template:   '<p ui-view="">...loading...</p>',  //'index4template.html',
    controller: function($state){ $state.go("about.child"); },
    //controller: 'AboutController as vm',
})

// this state is triggered in the controller above
// and it will take 2,5 second to do all the resolve stuff
.state('about.child', {
    template:   '<p>about here title: {{vm.title}}</p>',  
    controller: 'AboutController as vm',
    resolve: {
        title: function($timeout){
            return $timeout(function(){
               return 'from title function';
            }
            , 2500 // wait 2,5 second - and then replace ...loading...
            );
        }
    }
```

The idea behind is to load some **template** *(e.g. `...loading...`)*, as a parent view. Once instantiated (loading is displayed) we redirect to our child. In the example above, there is 2,5 second delay (loading form server), and then the child replaces parent fully...

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wd1mSbsnI6Wi0Cd4d4ZK?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @Radim.  This solves my problem nicely by putting the resolve in the child. I don't see any drawbacks and this seems a lot cleaner than doing the bootstrap stuff, yet gets the same result since you can't get to the about.child without the title function running (in my case I'll put my resource stuff there)

Answer (score 0):

Based in @Radim example, a more clearer aproach that worked for me:

If you are using ui-router then you could resolve this using nested states. For example:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("main", {
        url: "/",
        template: '<div ui-view></div>',
        controller: 'InitController'
    })
    .state("main.landing", {
        url: "landing",
        templateUrl: "modules/home/views/landing.html",
        controller: 'LandingPageController'
    })
    .state("main.profile", {
        url: "profile",
        templateUrl: "modules/home/views/profile.html",
        controller: 'ProfileController'
    });
```

In this example you have defined 3 routes: "/", "/landing", "/profile"

So, InitController (related to "/" route) gets called always, even if the user enters directly at /landing or /profile

**Important:** Don't forget to include `<div ui-view></div>` to enable the child states controller load on this section